# iOS UIScrollView with autosizable content

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, scrollview

Is it true the `UIScrollView` should have only one `UIView` inside? Using `addSubview` method you can add multiple elements inside.

QUESTION:
I'm adding elements directly to the scroll view. Assume the `contentSize` of the scroll view is 1000px height. I add a `UIButton` on it and place it at the bottom with `autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin`. If I extend the height of the content to 2000px I would like this button to stay at the bottom. How can I achieve this when adding elements directly to the scroll view?

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

A `UIScrollView` can have as many subviews as you want. Just add them and update `contentSize` properly.

When zooming in a scroll view there is however only a single subview that will be zoomed. So if you intend for zooming content, then a single subview is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

To you first question, no -- `UIScrollView` can have as many subviews as you want. Typically you keep track of which subviews you have put into the scrollview so that you can remove them when they are not visible (and save some memory). This is pretty much the point of `UIScrollView`.

To your second question, YMMV, but in my experience `UIScrollView` doesn't seem to pay attention to the `autoresizingMask` attribute of its subviews, so you wil have to manually keep your UIButton pinned towards the bottom of your `UIScrollView` as you change its size -- wherever you set the `UIScrollView`'s contentSize is the spot to adjust your `UIButton`'s frame.